# Getting actual widh/height values of element via attributes.getNamedItem

Tags: javascript, dom, height, width

i am tring to get the width/height values of an element in dom tree (HTML page) and i am using below method:

`var event = e || window.event;

var target = event.target || event.srcElement;`

i am getting id and class information by using

`var classinfo = target.attributes.getNamedItem("class").nodeValue;

var idinfo = target.attributes.getNamedItem("id").nodeValue;`

but as you can guess, any elemen doesn't have to has id and/or class nodes so i can't check **width="..px"** node value or **getElementById** method

As a result, is there any way to get width and height values of a node element by using **getNamedItem** method / or any other you can advise.
**NOTE:** I need to get real width and height not css or inline because maybe width is 60% in css but it is rendered as 100px...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

element.offsetWidth, element.offsetHeight: overall size of the containing box in pixels

element.clientHeight, element.clientWidth: content dimensions

These are **read only** properties, and always return the current rendered values.

(You need to assign a style property in the element or in a stylesheet to **set** most elements onscreen height and width.)

Comment: scrollHeight is what I would consider the height of the content of the container, I guess the difference is the meaning of "content". Both clientHeight and offsetHeight are the same for me for a basic div with lots of divs inside it and overflow:auto. scrollTop+clientHeight=scrollHeight (when scrolled to the bottom).